# Meteor - Template ONLY Events?

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to create a Meteor event for template only?

For example:

```
'click': function(){}
```

This will work anywhere on the browser, whether or not the clicked element was part of the template. What if I want to register an event for the template only? Is the only way to achieve this by doing 'click #DOM_ELEM_NAME' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events *are* captured only within the template that defines them:

```js
Template.leaderboard.events({
  "click .button": function (event) {
    console.log('Only buttons in the leaderboard template trigger this');
  }
});
```

You shouldn't need to put ids in event selectors. Read more at [Event maps](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps).

Comment: You're right. Sorry I thought I was clicking outside the template but I was.